# Finding all rational $p,q,r$ satisfying $p\cos{\frac{\pi}{7}}+q\cos{\frac{2\pi}{7}}+r\cos{\frac{3\pi}{7}}=1$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find all rational numbers $p,q,r$ such that
>   $$p\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{7}}+q\cos{\dfrac{2\pi}{7}}+r\cos{\dfrac{3\pi}{7}}=1.$$

My idea: we can find $x=\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{7}}$ the equation root?

Because we have 
$$8 \cos^3{\frac{\pi}{7}} - 4 \cos^2{\frac{\pi}{7}} - 4 \cos{\frac{\pi}{7}}+1=0,$$
 then
$$8x^3-4x^2-4x+1=0.$$

Comment: You have $54$ questions and $0$ accepted answers. I don't even know what to say.

Comment: Why does your $p,q$ and $r$ vanish?

Comment: @Git Gud, I can raise some interesting questions to let everybody to think together no？

Comment: @math110 Your point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x = \cos \frac{\pi}{7}$. Using double/triple angle formulas for the cosine, the given expression is equal to
$$p x + q (2x^2 - 1) + r(4x^3 - 3x) = 1 \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad (4r)x^3 + (2q)x^2 + (p - 3r)x + (-q-1) = 0.$$
As already mentioned, we know that 
$$8x^3 - 4x^2 - 4x + 1 = 0.$$
Since this polynomial is the unique third degree polynomial (with rational coefficients, and unique up to scalar multiplication) for which $\cos \frac{\pi}{7}$ is a root, it follows that there must exist a rational $k$ such that
$$(4r)x^3 + (2q)x^2 + (p - 3r)x + (-q-1) = k(8x^3 - 4x^2 - 4x + 1).$$
It then follows that
$$\begin{align} 4r &= 8k \\ 2q &= -4k \\ p - 3r &= -4k \\ -q-1 &= k \end{align}$$
Reducing this set of equations, we get
$$\begin{align} r &= 2k \\ q &= -2k \\ p &= 2k \\ q &= -k-1 \end{align}$$
This implies that $k + 1 = 2k$, i.e., $k = 1$, leading to the solution $(p,q,r) = (2, -2, 2)$.

Answer (score 3):

At first we call $\alpha=\tfrac{\pi}{7}$ and we are having the expression
\[ p \cdot \cos(\alpha) + q \cos(2 \alpha) + r \cos(3 \alpha) = 1 \]
As \[\cos(\alpha+\beta)= \cos(\alpha) \cos(\beta) -\sin(\alpha) \sin(\beta)\]
we know that 
\[ \cos(2\alpha) =\cos^2 (\alpha) -\sin^2 (\alpha)\]
and 
\[\cos(3 \alpha) = \cos(\alpha) \cos(2\alpha)- \sin(\alpha) \sin(2\alpha)\]
As 
\[ \sin(2\alpha) = 2 \cos(\alpha) \sin(\alpha)\]
we get 
\[ \cos(3 \alpha) = \cos(\alpha) ( \cos^2(\alpha) -\sin^2(\alpha) ) - \sin(\alpha) 
 (2 \cos(\alpha) \sin(\alpha)) \]
Expanding this gives us 
\[ \cos(3\alpha) = \cos^3(\alpha) -\cos(\alpha) \sin^2(\alpha) - 2\sin^2(\alpha)  \cos(\alpha)\]
and simplifying lead to 
\[ \cos(3\alpha) = \cos^3(\alpha) -3 \cos(\alpha) \sin^2 (\alpha) \]
So back to our original equation 
\[ p\cdot \cos(\alpha) + q \cdot \cos(2 \alpha) + r \cdot \cos(3\alpha)=1\]
Now we plug in the stuff above and get
\[ p \cdot \cos(\alpha) + q \cdot (\cos^2 (\alpha) -\sin^2 (\alpha) ) + r \cdot (
\cos^3(\alpha)- \cos(\alpha) \sin^2 (\alpha))=1\]
This is nearly fine but the $\sin^2(\alpha)$ terms are still annoying, we use that $\cos^2(\alpha)+\sin^2(\alpha)=1$ and hence $\sin^2(\alpha)=1-\cos^2(\alpha)$ so our equation is equal to 
\[ p \cdot \cos(\alpha) + q \cdot (\cos^2(\alpha) - 1 +\cos^2(\alpha)) + r \cdot (\cos^3(\alpha) -3 (1-\cos^2(\alpha)) \cos(\alpha)=1\]
Expanding this gives us 
\[ p \cdot \cos(\alpha) + q \cdot (2 \cos(\alpha)-1) + r\cdot (4\cos^3(\alpha) -3\cos(\alpha))=1\]
Now we call $\gamma=\cos(\alpha)$ and have
\[ p \cdot \gamma  + q \cdot 2 \gamma^2 - q +r4  \gamma^3 -r3 \gamma =1\]
Now we sort it in powers of $\gamma$
\[ 4r\gamma^3+2\cdot q \cdot  \gamma^2+ \gamma(p-3r)-q=1\]

Comment: It should be $p \cdot \gamma+q \cdot (2\gamma^2-1)+r \cdot (4\gamma^3-3\gamma)$. Now $\gamma$ has degree 3, so this cubic must be a real multiple of its minimal polynomial $8x^3-4x^2-4x+1$.

Comment: @IvanLoh oh right sry I confused myself