# What is the value of $ \int_{0}^{\infty}\;\left(\frac{\tan^{-1}{(x)}\cdot\tan^{-1}{(\frac{x}{2})}\cdot\tan^{-1}{(\frac{x}{3})}}{1+x^{2}}\right)\;dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

find  the value
$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}\;\left(\frac{\tan^{-1}{(x)}\cdot\tan^{-1}{(\frac{x}{2})}\cdot\tan^{-1}{(\frac{x}{3})}}{1+x^{2}}\right)\;dx$$

I think  the integral is very interesting.Thank you .

Comment: We appreciate your formatting efforts, but we encourage users to **not** use "displaystyle" in titles ;-)  $\quad$ Also, why do you find the integral interesting? What have you *tried*?

Comment: because long ago,I have see a same intergral.

Comment: And long ago I saw a lizzard running under the sun, yet I find lizzards pretty boring (not a zoologist, indeed), so again: why do you think this integral is interesting and what have you done to crack it?

Comment: Thank you ,wait, I look for this problem come from

Comment: @math110 You should get a badge for [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/58742/math110?tab=questions). Out of $62$ questions you have $0$ accepted answers. I've told you about this [before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347218/finding-all-rational-p-q-r-satisfying-p-cos-frac-pi7q-cos-frac2-pi#comment746854_347218). Of course you don't have to care about what I say, but I find this behaviour to not be good policy on your part.

Comment: @math110 What exactly is the point of offering a bounty when you don't accept an answer? You need to bring your accepted rate from 0% to 100% or no one is going to help you. If you don't accept, no one gets the bounty therefore no one will try to help you.

Comment: sorry,I don't know How accept.

Comment: @math110 To accept an answer, you need to click the green checkmark below the downvote arrow. Once you click the checkmark, the answer will be "accepted".

Comment: What have you tried? I'd try $t=\cfrac{1}{x}$ or developing some arctan into series.

Answer (score 1):

Maple won't do that one, but it will do this:
$$
\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {\arctan \left( x \right) \arctan \left( x/2 \right) }{{x}^{2}+1}}{dx}=\frac{\pi}{24}\, \left( {\pi }^{2}-6\,\mathrm{Li}_2\left(1/3 \right)  \right) \approx 1.0043049967766
$$

Answer (score 0):

```
$ maxima
(%i16) quad_qagi((atan(x)*atan(x/2)*atan(x/3))/(1+x^2),x,0,inf);
(%o16)         [.8936318109508621, 9.894245014971186E-12, 75, 0]
```

%o16 => [an approximation to the integral,
the estimated absolute error of the approximation,
the number integrand evaluations,
an error code.]